# powershell script to pull cpu/mem from list of servers

Tags: powershell

I have this PS script to pull CPU/MEM from a list of servers. It is working but instead of running once, it continues to run every minute. Dont know how to code it to stop once it runs once. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
while ($true) {
    $computers = Get-Content -Path F:\\data\\Computers.txt

    $output = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        $date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        $totalRam = (Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $computer | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).Sum
        $cpuTime = (Get-Counter '\\Processor(\_Total)% Processor Time' -ComputerName $computer).CounterSamples.CookedValue
        $availMem = (Get-Counter '\\Memory\\Available MBytes' -ComputerName $computer).CounterSamples.CookedValue

        "{0} {1} \> CPU: {2:#.###}%, Avail. Mem: {3:N0}MB ({4:#.#}%)" -f $computer,$date,$cputime,$availMem,(104857600 \* $availMem / $totalRam)
    }
    $output | Out-File "f:\\data\\filetest.csv" -Append
}
```

computers.txt file:
abc0wxxxp001
abc0wxxxp002

Output looks like this:

```
abc0wxxxp001 2024-02-02 08:32:40 \> CPU: 67.133%, Avail. Mem: 4,806MB (9.8%)
abc0wxxxp002 2024-02-02 08:32:42 \> CPU: 76.04%, Avail. Mem: 8,552MB (17.4%)
```

To reiterate, I need this to only run once as it reads computer.txt file and then stop. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `while ($true) { }` is a loop that will continue to run while true, so forever until it is stopped.  Remove or comment this out and it will only run once.

Comment: The code contains syntax errors and needs to be changed to work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel says, drop the ethernal loop.

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path F:\data\Computers.txt

$Output = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
  $Date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

  $TotalRam = (
    Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $Computer | 
      Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum
  ).Sum

  $CpuTime = (
    Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time' -ComputerName $Computer
  ).CounterSamples.CookedValue

  $AvailMem = (
      Get-Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes' -ComputerName $Computer
  ).CounterSamples.CookedValue

  "{0} {1} \> CPU: {2:#.###}%, Avail_Mem: {3:N0}MB ({4:#.#}%)" -f $Computer, $Date, $Cputime, $AvailMem, ($AvailMem / $TotalRam * 1MB * 100)

}

$Output | Out-File "F:\data\filetest.csv" -Append
```

Now, if you'd like to speed things up, you can use jobs.
(I've not tested the script below)

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path F:\data\Computers.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {

  Start-Job -Name "GetCounters_$Computer" {

    $Date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    $TotalRamJob = Invoke-Command $Computer {(
        Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | 
          Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum
      ).Sum
    } -AsJob

    $CpuTimeJob = Invoke-Command $Computer {(
        Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time'
      ).CounterSamples.CookedValue
    } -AsJob

    $AvailMemJob = Invoke-Command $Computer {(
        Get-Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes'
      ).CounterSamples.CookedValue
    } -AsJob

    $TotalRam = Receive-Job $TotalRamJob -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
    $CpuTime  = Receive-Job $CpuTimeJob  -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
    $AvailMem = Receive-Job $AvailMemJob -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

    "{0} {1} \> CPU: {2:#.###}%, Avail_Mem: {3:N0}MB ({4:#.#}%)" -F $Computer, $Date, $CpuTime, $AvailMem, ($AvailMem / $TotalRam * 1MB * 100)

  }#end countersjob
  
}#end foreach computer

Get-Job 'GetCounters_*' |
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob |
    Out-File "F:\data\filetest.csv" -Append
```